# How to Install third-party libs to Python 3.X when two other 2.Xs are also on MacOs?

Tags: python, macos, numpy, python-module

I have Python2.6, 2.7 and 3.4 on my Mac.
Yesterday I was trying to install Numpy to Python3.4, then I realized I don't really know how to install third-party libs(or modules) on MacOS, but I had some experience on Win8 before, so I tried and typed `pip3 install numpy` in terminal, and it worked! But here comes my questions-what if I typed `pip install numpy`, will it go straight to 2.6 or 2.7, or both? (Well, since Numpy is already there for both 2.Xs, I didn't test it on my own.) And is this `pip` the only way to specialize the installations? What else? Besides, is there also a lib or libs directory under Python on MacOS? Where can I find them to check whether some modules are already there or not?

Comment: I suggest you look into `virtualenv`. You can also see what `python` refers to with `which python`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I heard of it before when I was looking through some Flask files, it seems quite popular these days, do you use it a lot?

Comment: Yes, I find it's the easiest way to deal with having different requirements for different projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

But especially look at the second answer (not the accepted one).

If you download the source for `pip`, you can then install it using different python versions (via `easy_install`) and it will give you versioned copies of `pip` that know where to install other packages.

That gets you bootstrapped, and then you can `pip3.4 install -U pip` to keep it up to date.

Oh, I do wish `homebrew` would bring back the recipes for different python versions.

Comment: So that means if I want Numpy goes to python2.6, I can just type pip2.6, and pip2.7 for python2.7, I got it!

Comment: Yes. But for serious python work (especially on OSX) you **really** need to use `virtualenv`